# A link can pass a keyword, how to make a mysql query to pick it uo?

Tags: mysql

I have a book database with 80 different category pages, and at present 80 different pages, one for each. They only differ by the search term!
I want to pass the relevant keyword(s)in the menu link BUT how do I write the relevant mysql search query to pick up the one or more keywords from the url and produce the page?
This way one generic page picks up the keywords being passed to it and serves it up.

Comment: It's not too clear exactly what you are asking. Please post your existing code and explain the expected result, and how that differs from what you are actually seeing

Comment: [mcve] please ...

Comment: Drop down menu with 80 choices. Each option goes to a unique page such as >>anitabooks-military.co.uk/menu-ancient-16th.php

That page has a mysql query using the keywords "ancient" and "16th" and serves the page of books.
>>keywords LIKE '%ancient%' AND keywords LIKE '%16th%' AND status <> 'sold'<<

I want only ONE page using the menu option URL with the keywords passed as a GET or POST, and construct the mysql query using those keywords to produce the page of books.

I cant find a query to accept the keywords from the URL and use them.